# Import class dynamically in Python

Tags: python

I want to dynamically load a class from a given string. However, I do not know which file the class will be in, so I will have to search all files. I've tried this, but I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MyClass'` even though I'm 100% sure that that module (in the current iteration) has that class:

```
target = 'MyClass'
module_names = [mf[0:-3] for mf in os.listdir('application/models') if mf.endswith(".py")]
modules = [imp.new_module(x) for x in module_names]
for module in modules:
    try:
        target_class = getattr(module, target)
    except ImportError, AttributeError:
        continue

if target_class:
    print 'found class'
```

It seems I'm getting really close. What I want is not to limit the search to just one folder, but perhaps multiple folders. What's wrong with my code?

Edit: Ok now I'm trying something like this, but still getting the same error:

```
    for m in module_names:
        try:
            x = reload(__import__(m))
            target_class = getattr(x, target)
        except ImportError, AttributeError:
            continue
        else:
            break

    if target_class:
        print 'found class'
```

Comment: You probably want a `break` once you've found the `target_class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [`imp.new_module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.new_module), the returned module is **empty**.  Meaning that it will never contain your class.

Perhaps what you want to do is add your target directory to `sys.path` and use `__import__` to dynamically import those modules, then check for your class?

---

The following code works for me:

```
modules = ['foo','bar']
for mod in modules:
    try:
        x = reload(__import__(mod))
    except ImportError:
        print "bargh! import error!"
        continue
    try:
        cls = getattr(x,'qux')
    except AttributeError:
        continue

a = cls()
print a.__class__.__name__
```

Where `foo.py` and `bar.py` are in the same directory:

```
#foo.py
class foo(object):
    pass
```

and:

```
#bar.py
class qux(object):
    pass
```

Comment: Are you getting `ImportError` or `AttributeError`?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MyClass'`

Comment: Ahh so the key was to separate the ImportError and AttributeError into separate try statements. Now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.new_module) `new_module` returns and *empty* module:

> imp.new_module(name)
>       Return **a new empty module** object called name. This object is not inserted in sys.modules.

You may want to look at [imp.load_source](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_source) instead. This is just a simple example:

```
class Test:
    pass
```

And

```
In [19]: m = imp.load_source("test", "./test.py")
In [20]: getattr(m, "Test")
Out[20]: <class test.Test at 0x1fe6120>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the example in the [imp documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#examples):

File in same directory named hello.py:

```
def myFunction():
        return "Hello World!"
```

Import hello dynamically (w/o try except finally):

```
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module("hello")
hello = imp.load_module("hello", fp, pathname, description)
hello.myFunction() # returns 'Hello World!'
```